# masterpage control over content page in asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How can I get the masterpage control over content page .

like in asp.net code behind we use :

**`Master.FindControl("controlID").Visible = false;`**

now the same work I have do in my Asp.net MVC application .

Answer (score 0):

MVC doesn't work the same way as web forms, because you don't have all the overhead of maintaining "controls" in memory you can't just find the control and set it to not be visible. Instead, in your MVC 3 layout, you could put an if statement over the `@RenderBody()` call which would let you control whether or not to render the content page. Other than that, you could add a value to the view bag and then your content page could have an if statement to decide whether to render a specific portion of your content. With the added simplicity and performance boost of MVC comes the loss of a few conveniences...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that. before doing that , jus add the registry of the master page on the Content page (the page you want the masterpage control.)